# Let a function return nothing, not even "None" in Python 2.7.10 - possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, edx

Is there any way to prevent a python function to return **anything**, even `None`? I would need an output like:

```
[...]

[...]
```

but I always get:

```
[...]
None
[...]
```

If requested, I can upload the source code as well, but it's a bit long.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: No. Functions will always return something, `None` if nothing is specified. Just don't assign the result of the function to anything.

Comment: it looks like you're printing `None` where you want to be printing a blank line (`'\n'`).  so print `'\n'` instead . . . or `''`.

Comment: I upvoted your question - but only for the title! Your example is not very clear. Imho you should reduce the text you are printing and make it as minimal as possible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so looking at your code I assume you are printing the last line of code that generates the end results being "Goodbye! Total score: 9 points.".
What you need to do is instead of printing that line return it and print the function call like shown below.
Also functions always return something be it a string, a int or whatever type of data you set it to.
If you choose to not return anything it will always return None.
For if you are wondering what the \n is for it's to open up a new line because it seems like you want the space of a line between sessions of your game.
If not you can get rid of the \n it doesn't affect the outcome.
Anyway hope this helps!

```
def no_name():
    # return the line of code that generates this outcome instead of printing it
    #to get rid of the None.


    return "Goodbye! Total score: 9 points.\n"



print no_name()
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope. Just check with `if output is None:` and change the output accordingly.

Comment: What I think the OP is asking is what to do if the output is `None`, how to make Python return nothing? eg `[1, 3]` instead of `[1, None, 3]`. In the case `if output is not None: return output`, the implicit else would still return `None` which is "something".

Answer (score 2):

In Python an expression will **always** have to produce a result. [Function calls are expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), and are no exception here. As a result, *any callable*, including functions, produce a result, even if that result is `None`. From the documentation:

> A call always returns some value, possibly `None`, unless it raises an exception.

You could just test for `None`:

```
result = functioncall()
if result is not None:
    # ...
```